# I want some text to change color when the user checks a checkbox

Tags: javascript

When the user ticks the checkbox next to some text, I want the text to change color.

This is the code I have:

```
<p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">
   I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
   <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" />
</p>
```

This is the function I have so far:

```
function hasTickedBox( checkBoxID) {
   var chkbx = document.getElementById( checkBoxID );
   if ( chkbx.checked ) {
      //change the font color 
   } else {
      //do nothing 
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to ever *call* `hasTickedBox`.  What do you want the trigger for that to be?

Comment: Sorry. I want the trigger to be the user checking the checkbox.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you are looking for is `.style.color`

**Updated code**

```
<p id="termsP" style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
<input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" /></p>


function hasTickedBox( checkBoxID) {
    var chkbx = document.getElementById( checkBoxID );
    if ( chkbx.checked ) {
        document.getElementById('termsP').style.color = "#000000";
    }
}
```

Comment: Except you want to change the color of the `<p>`, not the checkbox.

Comment: And how would I change the colour of <p> rather than chkbx?

Comment: Thanks, man! So now, if I place the function in the head section and the <p> and checkbox in the body, it should work?

Comment: would I use: onchange="hasTickedBox(this.checkBoxID)"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jquery, you could do something like this

```
if(chkbx.checked) {
    $(chkbx).parent().css('color', 'new-color');
else {
   $(chkbx).parent().css('color', 'old-color');
}
```

If you aren't using jquery, it would be something like

```
chxbx.parentNode.style.color = "new-color";
```

obligatory fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tv5ta/