# Parent selector in css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, selector

How can I get the parent element by reference with their child element using pure css?

```css
#checkbox{
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#checkbox:checked (parentName){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
  click me
</label>
```

I know we can simply use jQuery to find the parent of the child element. Something like this;-

```
$(this).parent().css({'color': 'red'});
```

Is there anyway to identify the parent selector using pure css selector?

Comment: You can't. Zillions of same question in stackoverflow. Search first!!!

Comment: Maybe there is pseudo selector for parent element like `:parent`

Comment: Instead of vote my comment, mark to close as duplicated. I can't understand why vote my comment and not vote to close.

Comment: I just checkout here, i cant find out something related to this question folks!

Comment: I voted as so @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: Please check this link : https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css
maybe this will help

Comment: Hope this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969565/i-want-some-text-to-change-color-when-the-user-checks-a-checkbox

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude it's the most asked question in the CSS tag ...

Comment: @vals I know. It's because I said it

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to identify the parent selector using pure css selector?

No.

Still we don't have parent selector in native css. but in coming future that might be possible as some css methods are now available.

A simple workaround to your issue can be solved like wrapping the text content of parent `label` in some element like `span`:

```css
#checkbox{
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#checkbox:checked + span{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
  <span>click me</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I do not understand why have people downvoted a concise answer.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde I'm not the downvoter, but I think this is a over-duplicated question.

Comment: That's not the fault of the user answering.

Comment: I guess i just answered what was asked.....that's it. I don't know if anything i miss.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde I agree, but this community works as this. I grow many downvotes in my questions only because some discussions in unrelated topics. Imagine a perfect world.... stackoverflow is not.

Comment: @Jai, you did it the right job. Now i can understand from your answer.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde Because this is a duplicate answer and question and it encourages no research from OP, these questions shouldn't be answered, I can downvote for whatever reason I find valid and this I find valid, -1.

Comment: @MartinDawson i answered it because OP has tried something and it shows he might have researched a little. Because he done something and failed to achive that. I answered it. and it almose a year old post. Yet you are welcome.